# How to enable method level security having 2 different authorization and authentication managers?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a user based security in my application that serves all the requests with prefix /app.

Now, I have created few RESTFul services in my application prefixed by /rs and have used Spring security Oauth2 to protect those resources.

I have successfully protected these resources using xml configuration. However, I want to enable method level security as well.

As I read that we should have only one  tag in application. Also, method level security depends on the authentication mgr and authorization manager. Both the authentication manager as well as authorization managers are different based on http prefix. In this case, how can I enable method level security.
I am using xml based security configuration. Please suggest.

Comment: "As I read that we should have only one tag in application."
You mean the XML <http/> tags? Where did you read that? Clearly you need more than one if you have 2 sets of resources with different authentication requirements.

Comment: @DaveSyer: OP speaks of **method** security and the reference manual indeed says *You should only declare one `<global-method-security>` element*.

Comment: Do you have already method security enabled in one part and want to extend it the the other part, and if not, do you want it on one or both parts ?

Comment: Sorry for very late reply.

Comment: I am referring to <global-method-security> tag. As i have 2 different url patterns in my application (one with /rs and other with /app).

Comment: We have applied method level security in our application. Now we wanted it to extend it for both the parts  , i.e. ever those RESTFul services exposed with /rs. How can I acheive this?